# Exclude "empty" folders from ls output when using --ignore

Tags: ls

Suppose I have a folder with lots of subfolders and they are only supposed to contain archived files and I want to check that there are no other file types.

I can use the command

`ls -l -R /backup --ignore="*.zip" --ignore="*.7z"`

This will display this information I need, but also include every folder name e.g.

```
/backup/2000/Jan:
total 0

/backup/2000/Feb:
total 0
```

etc

Is there any way of excluding details of folders which only contain the ignored files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a folder with lots of subfolders and they are only supposed to contain archived files and I want to check that there are no other file types

This doesn't look like a job for `ls`. It looks like a job for [`find`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&apropos=0&sektion=1). Ask it to list regular files that don't match the patterns for archive files.

```
find /backup -type f ! -name '*.zip' ! -name '*.7z'
```

Add `-ls` at the end if you want to see the same kind of information as `ls -l` and not just the file names. (Not available in all `find` implementations.)

Comment: Thanks. I had previously ruled out using find as I didn't know about the -ls option and wanted the extra information.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few solutions.  Easiest may be to use the shell's extended globbing.

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -l **/*!(.zip|.7z)
```

You can also use `find`.

```
find /backup -type f ! \( -name "*zip" -o -name "*7z" \)
```

The first command will exclude hidden directories, the second will not.

Comment: I can't get the ls command to work as it still includes the zip and 7z files (And shopt shows than extglob is on)